# Jenkins Post Build Step only if there is a change in GIT/SVN

Tags: git, maven, svn, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have job which builds a maven project and runs sonar as a post build step and then with another build step, deploys the WAR file.
Since the code base is huge, I dont want to run sonar every time I do a deployment. Requirement is, when the user triggers the job, the sonar build step should only be performed, if there is a change in the code base from the last build. If no change, skip the test. Any idea or a plugin which can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Git Plugin, Environment Variables](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin#GitPlugin-Environmentvariables):

> The git plugin sets several environment variables you can use in your scripts:
>
> - `GIT_COMMIT` - SHA of the current
> - ...
> - `GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT` - SHA of the previous built commit from the same branch

If these are the same, there was no change. Use them in the [Conditional BuildStep Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin) to decide whether SonarQube shall run or not.

Comment: Thanks Gerold. This works fine. Now all I need is something similar for SVN.